# Is there a safe and legal way to use airplanes in laser tag?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, laser-illumination

Would there be a safe and legal way to use airplanes in [laser tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_tag)? The pilot would not be shooting to avoid distractions; a passenger would do it. Could shooting an infrared laser tag gun at a plane cause any problems? Would it matter if planes shot at each other or people on the ground shot at planes? If it's safe, what's the lowest altitude at which the plane[s] could safely fly?

I read the [question about paintball](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/is-it-legal-to-drop-shoot-paintballs-from-an-airplane) and its answers, but I think laser tag will be safe. There are no physical projectiles (other than photons), and since it's infrared, I don't think it will have the normal dangers of lasers, but I'm not entirely sure.

Also, this part isn't exactly about aviation, but would typical laser tag guns have enough range to shoot a plane from the ground or a target on the ground from a plane?

Comment: Laser tag guns will not have an effective range of anywhere near 500ft, the closest range you should even be thinking about. Also laser tag guns rely on activating sensors worn on the body, which they won't hit inside a solid object like a plane. Don't even think about this.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't play laser tag, but I did some Googling and found laser tag guns with 400 foot range, so it's likely possible to make a gun with range to reach an airplane at 500 feet, and possibly higher. As for the sensors, the OP might be planning to make sensors to put on the outside of the plane? No idea how hard that would be or what the safety implications would be, but it would solve the problem of beams not reaching the aircraft occupants.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in regular ground-based laser tag. But there's a place in France where you can do (supervised) air-to-air laser tag. It's a bunch of former fighter pilots who got themselves two B&F FK 12, stationed somewhere around Bordeaux. [Website (French only)](https://www.air-combat-experience.fr/).